# Self join to combine two date columns with groupby count columns for both dates

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, select, count

I have Request Date and Pickup Date columns. They're similar but not the same. I'm currently using two separate queries and pandas to concat the 2 data frames. I'm running this in Flask using SQLAlchemy so everything in the WHERE will be passed variables. I'm using the text() method to just run raw SQL once I've tested it in DB Browser. I messed around but didn't make any progress trying to get my desired output using sql alone.

```
SELECT r.PUDate, COUNT(r.PUDate) as trips
FROM requests r
WHERE PULoc IN ("list of location ID's")
AND r.'TO' IN ("list of requestors")
AND ReqDate >= '2014-01-01'
AND ReqDate <= '2019-12-31'
AND PUDate >= '2014-01-01'
AND PUDate <= '2019-12-31'
GROUP BY PUDate
ORDER BY PUDate;
```

```
SELECT r.ReqDate, COUNT(r.ReqDate) as reqs
FROM requests r
WHERE PULoc IN ("list of location ID's")
AND r.'TO' IN ("list of requestors")
AND ReqDate >= '2014-01-01'
AND ReqDate <= '2019-12-31'
AND PUDate >= '2014-01-01'
AND PUDate <= '2019-12-31'
GROUP BY PUDate
ORDER BY PUDate;
```

The desired output I achieved in pandas is a date column with a unique list of the dates from the 2 date columns. Then request count and pickup count columns, with zeros in place of nulls since some dates are unique to one column or the other. Is a self join the way to go about this or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

One option is `union all`:

```
select xDate, sum(trips) trips, sum(reqs) reqs
from (
    select PULoc, to, r.PUDate xDate, 1 trips, 0 reqs from requests r
    union all
    select PULoc, to, r.ReqDate, 0, 1 from requests r 
) t
where 
    PULoc in ("list of location ID's")
    and to in ("list of requestors")
    and xDate >= '2014-01-01'
    and xDate < '2015-01-01'
group by xDate
order by xDate;
```

I moved the filtering conditions to the outer query so the query is easier to write. I would expect that the database should be able to push the predicates down to the subqueries - however if you are seeing performance issues, you can repeat the filtering conditions in the subqueries instead.